# Some problems adding data to ldap

Tags: macos, import, openldap

I'm trying to add some data to the ldap directory, but i get the following error.

```
sudo slapadd < ldapdata.txt
slap_sasl_init: auxprop add plugin failed
slapadd: slap_init failed!
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: When asking questions please paste the version of the software in question (in this case, the output of `slapd -V`); also, run the command with a "debug" or "verbose" switch (if it has one) and paste the output here (in this case, the output of `sudo slapadd -v < ldapdata.txt`.

Comment: Also, most of the time you will want to use `ldapadd` instead of `slapadd`. `ldapadd` talks the standard LDAP protocol and operates on **any** LDAP server, while `slapadd` uses an OpenLDAP-specific IPC protocol to communicate with OpenLDAP only. Generally `slapadd` is only used for debugging purpose since it exposes more OpenLDAP internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message, it seems the problem is during some internal initialization process, having not much to do with `slapadd` (ie. I guess you will get the same error with just `slaptest`). And according to [here](http://wiki.herzbube.ch/index.php/OpenLDAP#From_slapd-2.4.25-1.2Bb1_to_slapd-2.4.25-3),  you might have to install a newer version of OpenLDAP.

Comment: I gave up using the original ldap from osx and installed a new one from macports. Also I managed to make it work.